# Genism Phrase library not accepting common_terms

Tags: python, gensim

I am trying to use Gensim.phrases library to identify phrases in a text.

I used the following:

```
bigram = models.Phrases(txt_to_words,min_count=min_count, threshold=threshold,common_terms=common_terms)
```

And I get the error:

```
<ipython-input-13-1c8b06a0b078> in words_to_phrases(txt_to_words, min_count, threshold)
     33     common_terms=["of", "with", "without", "and", "or", "the", "a","in","to","is","but"]
     34 
---> 35     bigram = models.Phrases(txt_to_words,min_count=min_count, threshold=threshold,common_terms=common_terms)
     36 
     37     # trigram

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'common_terms'
```

I have the latest gensim package 2.0+

Any idea why it is not recognizing the common_terms parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Well... the latest version is `3.4.0`.
Try updating `gensim` using `pip install -U gensim`

This toy example works for me:

```
from gensim.models.phrases import Phrases
txt_to_words = [['first', 'sentence'], ['and', 'second', 'sentence']]
common_terms = ["of", "with", "without", "and", "or", "the", "a","in","to","is","but"]
bigram = Phrases(txt_to_words, min_count=1, common_terms=common_terms)
```

Comment: Something is really weird. I just updated to gensim 3.4.0 and still it gives the same error.

Comment: Others had a similar issue, documented at [gensim github](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1751). Before `gensim 3.1` there was no `common_terms` argument. Strange that updating did not fix this for you.

Comment: Yeah. I can see that my current gensim version i updated with pip in my conda env is 3.4.0. Still it doesn't recognize this parameter

Comment: So, when you run `gensim.__version__` in your code, you get `'3.4.0'`?